# Twisted with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, twisted

I have been experimenting with both Twisted and Tkinter. I've got a small program working where I can click a button within Tkinter and it will send a request off to a local server. This is done by calling MessageCFactory. This works fine, however when the server returns its reponse my 'data recieved' method does not catch it. This is probably due to me not understanding the reactor loop.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction

Thanks!

```
class Client(protocol.Protocol):


    def mainGUI(self):
    print("hello")
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    root = Tk()
    tksupport.install(root)
    root.geometry("300x300+200+200")
    root.title('GUI')
    root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))

    middleFrame = Frame(root)
    middleFrame.pack()

    Label(middleFrame, text="Initial IP").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
    initialIP = Entry(middleFrame, width=19)
    initialIP.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

    Label(middleFrame, text="Port").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
    initialPort = Entry(middleFrame, width=19)
    initialPort.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

    Label(middleFrame, text="Username").grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)
    username = Entry(middleFrame, width=19)
    username.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=W)
    Button(middleFrame, text='Enter',
           command=lambda arg1=initialIP, arg2=username: self.select(initialIP, initialPort, username)).grid(
        row=6, column=5, sticky=W)
    print("GUI")


def select(self, initialIP, initialPort, username):
    initialIP = str(initialIP.get())
    initialPort = str(initialPort.get())

    """
    General data sanitation from the UI into things that our twisted application can understand
    Encoding as bytes for transfer
    """
    username = str(username.get())
    usernameBytes = str.encode(username)
    initialPort = int(initialPort)

    reactor.connectTCP(initialIP, initialPort, MessageCFactory(usernameBytes))
    print("message: %s" % (username))


class MessageCProto(protocol.Protocol):
def connectionMade(self):
    self.transport.write(self.factory.message)
    self.transport.loseConnection()


def dataReceived(self, data):
    print('echo:', data)

class MessageCFactory(ClientFactory):
protocol = MessageCProto


    def __init__(self, message):
    self.message = message

    def dataReceived(self, data):
    print('echo:', data)


def main():
reactor.callLater(0, Client)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: I am not fully sure of what is causing your problem here but you will likely want to use threading when sending any kind of query to a server especially if you have to wait on a reply.

Comment: I've gotten a little further with this but still don't understand the problem. All the code executes fine, but print statements and log statements do not work.

Comment: well your print statements are not indented properly. Fix you indention and see how that goes.